# why mscorlib.dll contains BCL classes that also contained by other dlls

Tags: c#, .net

for example, `List<T>`

https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs

so I can say `mscorlib.dll` contains `List<T>` class. However, based on the info in VS, I can see that `List<T>` is in `System.Collections.dll`

why do we have this inconsistency?
[image]

Comment: .NET vs .NET Framework... Microsoft decided to take a mulligan. The newer .NET is what you want to use, the GitHub link is for the older .NET Framework.